# Attaching a mp3 file to email directly from app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on an app where, if the user selects a sound, they can email it to themselves from the app.

The attachment part 'appears' to work, however, when I send the email, the recipient has no attachment?

On the iPad/iPhone itself, it looks like it is attaching it when it comes to compose, but it is not working? :/

Here is the code I am using;

```
- (void)onSend:(id)sender{

    int nIndex;

    UIButton    *btnSender = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog( @"%d", btnSender.tag );

    for ( int i = 0; i < [ m_aryFileName count ]; i++ ) {

        if( i == ( btnSender.tag - 100 ) ){
            nIndex = i;
        }

    }

    NSString *strFileName = [ m_aryFileName objectAtIndex:nIndex ];
    strFileName = [ strFileName stringByAppendingString:@".mp3" ];
    NSData*     nData = [ NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strFileName ];

    MFMailComposeViewController *pickerMail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    pickerMail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [pickerMail setSubject:@"myMail Attachment"];

    // Attach an image to the email
    [pickerMail addAttachmentData:nData mimeType:@"audio/mp3" fileName:strFileName ];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"Here is your attachment";

    [pickerMail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:pickerMail animated:YES];
    [pickerMail release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a mime type of `audio/mpeg` instead. You can get this value by running the following code:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)@"mp3",
                                                        NULL);
CFStringRef mimeTags = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
CFRelease(uti);
NSString *mediaType = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString *)mimeTags];
CFRelease(mimeTags);
```

How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

try this code mate,

```
NSString *strFileName = [m_aryFileName objectAtIndex:nIndex];
strFileName = [strFileName stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"];
NSURL    *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:strFileName];
NSData *nData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

MFMailComposeViewController *pickerMail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
pickerMail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[pickerMail setSubject:@"myMail Attachment"];
[pickerMail addAttachmentData:nData mimeType:@"audio/mpeg" fileName:strFileName ];
NSString *emailBody = @"Here is your attachment";
[pickerMail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:pickerMail animated:YES];
```

Comment: It just attaches a .txt file called ATT00001.txt  :(

Comment: Yes, it just attached the file as a .txt file not an mp3 file and it does not open.

Comment: did you see this 'mimeType:@"audio/mpeg"' ?

Answer (score 1):

Below code might be useful to you:

NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mediaUrl];

[mailcomposer addAttachmentData:videoData mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:@"Video"]

Comment: It worked, so did the other code If only I could give you both a correct answer :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] && m_pDataArray != nil) 
{
    NSString * pSongPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song" ofType"@"mp3"]; ;//get the file
    MFMailComposeViewController * pMailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    pMailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [pMailComposer setMessageBody:@"msg body" isHTML:NO];
    NSURL * pFileUrl = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pSongPath] autorelease];
    NSData * pData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pFileUrl] autorelease];
     [pMailComposer addAttachmentData:pData mimeType:@"audio/mpeg" fileName:@"song.mp3" ]];
     [self presentModalViewController:pMailComposer animated:YES];
     [pMailComposer release];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *pAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure" message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"                                                       delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [pAlert show];
    [pAlert release];
    pAlert = nil;
}
```

be sure that the file should have valid extension like .mp3 , in that case it will work properly